# Isomorphic groups with 4 elements

Tags: group-theory

I have written that all the groups with 4 element are isomorphic with Z4 or the Klein group. Can somebody explain me why,please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not cyclic, then all of its non-identity elements must have order 2 by Lagrange, and the subgroups that they separately generate must all be normal, as they have index 2, so it must be abelian, hence it must be the Klein group.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 elements in the group, one element being the identity. So you're left with 3 elements to 'fill in' the rest of the group, by Lagrange's Theorem the orders must divide 4 i.e be 2 or 4 (can't be 1 since it would be equal to identity). So the remaining 3 elements could potentially have orders 2,2,2 or 2,2,4 or 2,4,4 or 4,4,4. If you do some simple maths or construct a composition table for the group you'll very quickly find it's impossible to have the 3 elements having orders 2,2,4 or 4,4,4, so the only possibility is to have orders
1,2,2,2 or 1,2,4,4 in a group of 4 elements (these correspond to Klein group and Z/4Z, respectively.)